# Assetss from wwwroot cannot be found on Docker Image

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have got Linux VM Docker Image up and running but I have encountered one difficulity.

All assetss that were in my wwwroot folder cannot be found

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I have included

```
 "webroot": "wwwroot"
```

In project.json file but that doesn't fix the problem. One more thing is thaht running from VS 2015 (on ISS Express) everything works - is there something that I should include in Dockerfile as well?.

EDIT:

I added VOLUME to docker file but that did not help:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["kpm", "restore"]

VOLUME ["/wwwroot"]

EXPOSE 5004
ENTRYPOINT ["k", "kestrel"]
```

Comment: Did you declare it as a volume? (as in https://github.com/nasqueron/docker-nginx-php-fpm/blob/973c6e766cc3b59bf6930b1993895e1cd3822c06/Dockerfile#L83)

Comment: no I haven't - are there more declaration that I should take in consideration?

Comment: just declaring directory as volume doesn't put anything there. You need either to put files into this directory or map this volume to local directory using -v option - https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems

Comment: I can't get files from wwwroot folder to load in image ... and unfortunetly the documentation provided doesn't help

Comment: You cannot get files, because you need to put files there first, and document provided show one of the ways how to put files there. You created empty folder and now complaining that folder is empty.

Comment: so if I want to copy all data from /wwwroot folder to /wwwroot folder in image i should use VOLUME["/wwwroot","/wwwroot"]  ?

Answer (score 2):

are you working through the example here:  [asp](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/01/14/running-asp-net-5-applications-in-linux-containers-with-docker.aspx) ? I don't know much about asp, but, I think you are pretty close.  First, I don't think you need to modify the Dockerfile.  You can always mount a volume, the VOLUME keyword just declares it as necessary.  But, you do need to modify your project.json file like you have shown, with one difference:

```
"webroot": "/webroot"
```

I am assuming that the name is "webroot" and the directory to look in (for the project) is "/webroot".  Then, build it, like the example shows:

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

So, when you run this do:

```
docker run -t -v $(pwd)/webroot:/webroot -d -p 80:5004 myapp
```

What this docker run command does is takes your webroot directory from the current directory ($pwd) and mounts it in the container and calls that mount /webroot.  In other words, you container must reference /webroot (not webroot, that would be relative to WORKDIR I think).

I think the bottom line is there are two things going on here.  The first one is 'building' the image, the second one is running it.  When you run it you provide the volume that you want mounted.  As long as you application repects the project.json file's "webroot" value as the place to look for the web pages then this will work.

Comment: well in vNext (asp.net 5) all files such as .css and javasripts are stored in wwwroot but i tried this command with no luck :(

docker run -t -v $(pwd)/wwwroot:/webroot -d -p 80:5004 myapp

or

docker run -t -v $(pwd)/wwwroot:/wwwroot-d -p 80:5004 myapp

Comment: I have also changed in project.json webroot to "webroot" and tried command but still nothing

Comment: /webroot right? then you did a build, then a run, like i listed?

Comment: well i put webroot without / - because when i tested it with / i got some error that the folder doesn't exist (i'll do that again first thing tomorrow morning and let you know)

Comment: Ok I build ,run like you've listed but no luck.

Comment: It's sad to say but I forgot to use app.UseStaticFiles(); is StartUp.cs now it;s working